# Need to Detect the biggest circle in the image using circle hough transform

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation

I am trying to make a program that can detect biggest circle in the image. I am using `cv2.HoughCircles()` function for this purpose. But i am not getting desired results. The function is not detecting the circle. I also have to extract the extract the detected circle.

**Original Image.**

[image: Original Image]

**The Results I need.**

[image: The Result I need.]

The code I am using is:

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

image = cv2.imread('img.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
image = cv2.resize(image, (512, 512))
cv2.imwrite("Image.png", image)
imageCopy = image.copy()
image = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (5,5), 2)

ret, threshold_image = cv2.threshold(image, 28, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(threshold_image, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 40, param1=50, param2=30, minRadius=0, maxRadius=0)
circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))

# Finding Biggest Circle
radius = []
for i in circles[0, :]:
    radius.append(i[2])
max_radi = max(radius)


#Drawing Circles on Image
for i in circles[0, :]:
    if max_radi == i[2]:
        cv2.circle(imageCopy, (i[0], i[1]), (i[2]), (255, 255, 255), 5)
        cv2.circle(imageCopy, (i[0], i[1]), 15, (255, 255, 255), 5)


plt.subplot(131), plt.imshow(image, cmap = 'gray')
plt.title("Original"), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(132), plt.imshow(threshold_image, cmap = 'gray')
plt.title("threshold"), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(133), plt.imshow(imageCopy, cmap = 'gray')
plt.title("Circles Detected"), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

[image: Image Obatined after thresholding and circle hough]

Comment: I've edited your question do the images show up. Please observe how I did this so you can do it too in the future.

Comment: Perhaps you are trying to find the outer shape more similar to an elipse rather than a circle. Please provide a more accurate definition of what you are looking for, maybe the desired output on the image